# PDO error with FETCH_CLASS: General error: could not call class constructor

Tags: php, sql-server, class, oop, pdo

I am really stumped on this, I have used this method and pretty much this exact code in all of my database driven projects. For some reason it's not working this time.

I am getting the following error when I try to populate objects with database results:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::fetchAll() [pdostatement.fetchall]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: could not call class constructor in D:\vhosts\hoet.co.uk\httpdocs\mobile\classes\Pages.php on line 67
```

The thing is, if I get a single record from the database it works fine.

Here is the code for single, and all rows:

```
// Get a page
public static function get($search, $by = "id") {
    $db = new Data;
    $sql = $db->query("
        SELECT   *
        FROM     pages
        WHERE $by = :search
    ");
    $sql->bindParam(":search", $search);
    $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'Pages');
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll();
}


// Get all pages
public static function getAll($order = "title ASC") {
    $db = new Data;
    $sql = $db->query("
        SELECT   *
        FROM     pages
        ORDER BY $order
    ");
    //$sql->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'Pages');
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll();
} // This is line 67 in my file
```

I also have private vars setup within the class for each of the database columns.

The only difference on this project is that it is a MS database and uses the PDO mssql driver instead of the normal MySQL.

Comment: Okay, so it seems that if I limit the number of rows being pulled to below 25 it will work. To be this seems like a ridiculous limitation!

Comment: Since you use query() do you still need to execute again? and have you try to set the vars to public

Comment: the `$db->query` is a function of the Data class that is basically a shortened prepare. I know what the issue is now, the mssql driver doesn't allow more than 24 rows to be returned at once, I have no idea why and I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a bug.

I would try to get a row at the time, adjust to this:

```
public static function getAll($order = "title ASC") {
    $db = new Data;
    $sql = $db->query("
        SELECT   *
        FROM     pages
        ORDER BY $order
    ");
    $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'Pages');
    $sql->execute();
    // get one row at the time
    $data = array();
    while($row = $sql->fetch()){
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Would that still push the results to my class object?

Comment: this will build the same array fetching rows one by one

Comment: Still not working for me. Am I right in thinking the mssql PDO driver is no more?

Comment: how come you say it's working when you fetch less then 25 rows but not when using while? isn't one less then 25? you may have to specify explicitely fetch mode `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS)`